# Hibernate Entity Class for the properties in EntityPersister

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, event-listener, hibernate-criteria

I have implemented a `PreInsertEventListener` to capture the insert event. Now I am getting all the property names using the `event.getPersister().getPropertyNames()` method. Is there a way I can get the Entity Class of one of the individual properties ?

Comment: Does the `event.getEntity()` method match your needs?

Comment: That returns the Entity Object being inserted I am interested in the Entity Class of the Properties,